# Python download updated source page in selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to download the html content from this url https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20210328/ with this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20210328/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cmc-cookie-policy-banner__close").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cmc-table-listing__loadmore > button:nth-child(1)").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cmc-table-listing__loadmore > button:nth-child(1)").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cmc-table-listing__loadmore > button:nth-child(1)").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cmc-table-listing__loadmore > button:nth-child(1)").click()
data = driver.page_source
print(data)
```

I use the click function to press the "load more" button at the bottom of the page as I need not only the first 200 elements, but to reach at least 1000.
But when I print the page source, it shows me only the first 200, as if it were stopped at the html content of the first load of the page, and it does not take in account my actions on the page.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Try adding sleeps `time.sleep(2)` between the clicking on `load more` and after the last click before the `data = driver.page_source`. Please let me know if that makes changes

Comment: Unfortunately no, even with 60 seconds before printing the source page

Comment: No need to give more than 2-3 seconds in such case. I'll try to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer to your question, but some analysis of the web page you're trying to rip reveals it pulls data from this endpoint directly:

https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/historical?convert=USD,USD,BTC&date=2021-03-28&limit=200&start=401

This will return JSON which you can then import into Python more easily.

```
# import requests module
import requests
 
# Making a get request
response = requests.get('https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/historical?convert=USD,USD,BTC&date=2021-03-28&limit=200&start=401')
 
# print response
print(response)
 
# print json content
print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

With delays between the clicking on 'load more' and with adding delay after the last click before getting the `page_source` I see clicking on 'load more' does changing the content of `data = driver.page_source`
The code below shows me the initial `page_source` length is 396447 while the final `page_source` length is 946180

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20210328/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cmc-cookie-policy-banner__close").click()
time.sleep(2)
data = driver.page_source
print(len(data))
# print(data)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cmc-table-listing__loadmore > button:nth-child(1)").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cmc-table-listing__loadmore > button:nth-child(1)").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cmc-table-listing__loadmore > button:nth-child(1)").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cmc-table-listing__loadmore > button:nth-child(1)").click()
time.sleep(2)
data = driver.page_source
print(len(data))
# print(data)
driver.quit()
```

This code must be improved to remove the redundant hardcoded sleeps but basically it works.

Comment: The length of the html code is increased but in the content I stop at element 200 which is visible on page 1:
"rank":200}],"page":1,"sort":"","sortDirection":""}

Comment: I think the issue is because you can't see all the page_source content on your console. It's too long. Try outputting it to text file and then see it

Comment: No because there is a lot of html text visible after the end of the table.
I also tried with this code but it is the same, it stops at rank 200, with the "page sort 1", that 1 should be maybe 2/3/4 ..
with open ('readme.txt', 'w', encoding = "utf-8") as f:
            f.write (date)